# Why do we call majoritary charge carriers with this name since minority charge carriers must exist with same concentration?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

A hole is the lack of an electron.

Thus, if we consider for example a N doped semiconductor. The so-called "majority charge carriers" are the electrons. But whenever there is a mobile electron that moves from a site to another site, the former site will have a hole, thus I don't see why there would not be exactly the same number of holes as the number of electrons.

Thus, I don't catch why the electrons would be really "majoritary", for example in a N semiconductor.

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the explanation. Let's see other comments.

Comment: I am with you Mathieu. I won't buy that cheap argument, because electrons aren't particles but quasiparticles in solids, too.

Comment: If a semiconductor is doped n-type (for example), then there are (mobile) electrons in the conduction band even if the valence band is full (no holes) so I don't understand your argument.

Comment: Thank you Alfred. I believe that your explanation is the best one. Thank you.

Comment: Mathieu, please note that the contributor you're addressing your reply to will be notified if you (for example) include @Alfred in your reply. Give it a try.

Comment: @Alfred thank you. I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument only holds for undoped (intrinsic) semiconductors. Doping introduces one type of carriers and creates a strong asymmetry in the concentration of both carrier types.

Comment: All right thank you. Actually I feel that the best explanation was the one from Alfred Centauri.

Comment: Really? They are they same except that I pointed out your error in more detail.

Comment: ok, actually, Alfred gives an extra information, which is useful. Maybe you may merge his information in your answer, for people that may ask themselves the same question. Thank you.

Comment: Which extra information in which answer ? I only see a comment.

Comment: His useful information is that for my reasoning would work only if the valence band would not be full. If the valence band is not full, then to each electron of the conduction band there is a corresponding hole in the valence band. If the valence band is full, then there is no more equality of the number of electrons and holes. What do you think of this ?

Comment: I cannot follow your reasoning. You should read up on semiconductors.

Comment: Sure. Actually, I have read a lot on semiconductors, but most often, the books don't answer to all details that people could ask themselves.